# How to parse the webservice response?

Tags: android, android-webservice

I want to know how to parse the web service response data in android .Actually i m accessing the .net web service.I can get a result of some complex type.i want to know how to retrive a particular value from this complex type.Is there is any parser avilable to parse the content of the response or else we have to parse manually? If u have any code snippet pls bring me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - what content type you are talking about? XML and JSON are supported I believe. I've been using just plain HttpClient to get the responses

Comment: i have been talking about text/xml content.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to parse XML response, see here:
http://www.helloandroid.com/node/110
it's a sample XML RSS reader